# SVN Move with preserving logs/commits history

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to do "SVN Move versioned item(s) here" with Tortoise to move some files from one folder to another within the project. But I losing the logs/commits history when I do this. I think it's because of the manner Tortoise does moving of files: it deletes files in the old folder and creates (adds) these files to SVN to that new folder. That's why after operation I'm getting newly added files to the new folder with the clean log.

So can anyone give a hint if it possible to move files with preserving all logs in SVN?

Comment: Are you using tortoisesvn `show log` option? In the `show log` window, is the `stop on copy/rename` option unchecked?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Just a moment ago have found this checkbox and got read the whole log. All that was needed is to read message from Tortoise "For complete history deselect Stop on copy/rename" in the end of log. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: So this issue is resolved?

Comment: Maybe Dipu should convert his comment to an answer.

Comment: Yep. He can either convert his comment to an answer, or I can just delete this topic since it has been resolved very quickly and maybe not so interesting to preserve on StackOverflow. Or I can mark in the title of the topic "Solved: SVN Move with preserving logs/commits history". Which alternative are best?